# SQL Server PHP Code Igniter show one to many relationship

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

i want to show data from table_one,where tableone_id is included on table_two..which is one to many relationship..here is the example.

```
table_one                table_two
id  | name               id  | name |tableone_id
1   |   A                1   |   C  |     1
2   |   B                2   |   D  |     1
                         3   |   E  |     2
                         4   |   F  |     2
```

The result i was expecting on my PHP is..

```
Number  | Name | Linked Item |
  1     |  A   |    C        |
        |      |    D        |
  2     |  B   |    E        |
        |      |    F        |
```

i already tried some code like

```
**Controller.php**
$head = $this->db->query("SELECT * from table_one)->result_array();

foreach($head as $key => $value)
{
   $head[$key]['items'] = $this->db->query("SELECT
   a.id,
   b.id,
   b.name as tabletwo_name,
   FROM table_one a
   JOIN table_two b on a.id = b.id
   where b.id =".$value['id'])->result_array();
}
```

the code i make ,fails.how did i do the right code for that case ?
Thank you

Comment: Go for documentation buddy, you really misunderstood the sql.

Answer (score 0):

1. your db queries should be in the model, not in the controller
2. you are missing double quotes in the first select, your string is not closed
3. why are you selecting all results from table_one and then doing JOINed select? You are not even selecting the data you want to have in your output (like table_two.name).

Change your first query to:

```
$this->db->query("SELECT table_one.id as number, table_one.name as name, table_two.name as linked_item FROM table_one LEFT JOIN table_two ON table_one.id = table_two.tableone_id")->result_array();
```

and then just do this:

```
foreach($head as $key => $value)
{
   $head[$key]['items'] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, hmmm i have not test this but you can

```
   $this->db->select('table_one.name AS t1,table_two.name AS t2');
            $this->db->join('table_two', 'table_two.tableone_id=table_one.id');
            $rs = $this->db->get('table_one');

            $count = 1;
            $data  = array();
            foreach ($rs->result() as $key => $value)
            {
                    $data[] = array(
                        'number'      => $count ++,
                        'name'        => $value['t1'],
                        'linked_item' => $value['t2']
                    );
            }

            print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

the controller is for communicate between model and view in codeigniter. so your db query should in model.

make a model based on your query and maybe you can try like this:

```
function something(){

   $qry = 'a.* , b.tableone_id';

   $this->db->select($qry);
   $this->db->from('table_one as a');
   $this->db->join('table_two b', 'b.tableone_id = a.id', 'left');

   $q = $this->db->get();
   return $q;

}
```

try follow this link too for more reference on database reference in CI:
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html